# Fire an event on mouseClick in SWT?

Tags: java, mouselistener, swt

In SWT, for MouseListener interface, the methods available are `mouseUp()`, `mouseDown()` and `mouseDoubleClick()`

How to fire an event based on the user click?

We can do this by conjunction of `mouseUp()` and `mouseDown()` but isn't there any trivial solution like `mouseClick()` method in SWT?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of object?  Just a `Composite`?  (Most of the native wrapper types have SelectionListeners to implement this, but otherwise mouse down and mouse up are unambiguous.  "Click" less so.)

Comment: I am drawing an image using GC(GraphicsContext) How to fire an event when the user clicks on the image ?

Comment: You write "_How to fire an event based on the user click?_" What do you mean? The SWT listeners _listens_ for events from the display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would a mouse-click event be defined? Mouse-down followed by mouse-up without mouse leaving the bounds of the control (otherwise it would be drag-start), right? By that definition, mouse-click event couldn't be associated with a single point, but rather with an area (1) or a control (2). The first case wouldn't fit into generic SWT event, which only has a location (x and y), and you'd still need additional code to check whether the click area was inside your image. In the second case where the mouse-click would only be defined using a control (and no location), the event would be useless to you.

When you have implemented your own single-click detection you can fire any events on the control you like, even those not defined by SWT.

Comment: I am not getting the context where the mouseClick() event will be useless. Can you be a bit more explanative ?

Comment: @ynwa Updated my answer. This is just theoretical and doesn't change the fact that there is no MouseClick event in SWT :)

Answer (score 0):

To react on a mouse click event on a button you can use SelectionListener, something like this should do the trick:

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            super.widgetSelected(e);
            System.out.println("click!");
        }
    });
```