# Where is the MouseClick event on an SWT Button?

Tags: java, button, swt

I know this sounds like a very basic question, and I feel embarrassed to ask it but...

**How to I add a Mouse Click handler to an SWT button?**

What I checked:

- I can find tons of examples on how to add mouse down, mouse up or double click handlers (by assigning a [MouseListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseListener.html)). Obviously, mouse click (sequence of down and up on the same control) is something different than mouse down.
- I understand that there might not be a click handler on *generic* controls, but the only event I see added on the [Button control](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html) is a [SelectionListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html) -- that *might* be it, but selection sounds more like "received focus" to me than "was clicked or selected and then invoked with a key press".
- I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827929/fire-an-event-on-mouseclick-in-swt), whose answer basically says that you need to implement that yourself -- I find that a bit hard to believe.

Is *selection* what is commonly known as "OnClick" in other languages/frameworks? Or is there something else that I completely missed?

Comment: Yes, `SWT.Selection` or `SelectionListener` is what you're looking for. It might be called selection, because a `Button` can be a checkbox or a radion button depending on it's style.

Comment: @Baz: Great, thanks. Make that an answer and I will accept it -- hopefully it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `SWT.Selection` or `SelectionListener` is what you're looking for:

```
Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        System.out.println("SWT.Selection");
    }
});
```

adding a `SelectionListener` internally does the same as the code above.

It might be called selection, because a `Button` can be a checkbox or a radion button depending on it's style.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `SelectionListener` is what you are after. I, too, am more of a fan of the `OnClick` terminology myself as it is more cut and dry; I digress.

Here is a good example for you to see how it works:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingSelectionListener.htm